# Cutting information correctly from a String in Java

Tags: java

I'm reading a string in java from a .txt file says:

## E 1 2 W1

(I'm having it in a string variable)
now I want to cut the information into 3 variables:

```
v1 = 1
v2 = 2
w = 1
```

problem is numbers could occupy more bytes in example:

## E 12 204 W1

how do I easily take the 2nd, 3rd and 4th words into differents vars?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    String src = "E 12 204 W1";
    String[] numbers = src.split("\\D+");
    int v1 = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);
    int v2 = Integer.parseInt(numbers[2]);
    int w = Integer.parseInt(numbers[3]);
```

This particular version of `split` removes everything that's not a number. The first element (`numbers[0]`) is going to be an empty string so you can ignore it. The others will be the numbers, and only the numbers, so you can safely parse them into integers (unless you think there is a chance somebody will input a large number such as `98798765465498798798754`, in which case you will get an exception and you should catch and handle it).

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions for this problem. Visit the [`String API`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to see all methods that can serve your needs.

I won't show you a full solution but I'll try to guide you.

If the pattern is fixed, you can easily write a method that [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)s the String and assign the second, third and fourth variables in a loop.

You can also build a *regex* that extracts the wanted fields for you, e.g. `\d+\s+\d+\s+\w\d+`.

Answer (score 0):

If  this

```
E             12            204           W1
<token><space><token><space><token><space><token>
0              1            2             3
```

is your format, then you could just [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) your string using `" "` and get the elements with the index 1 and 2, from the element in index 3 remove the leading `W`